# How to install the Python-RSA 3.1.1 package in Python 3.2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rsa, python-2.x, python-3.2

So far I've tried these methods to install the package
 `pip install rsa` and`python setup.py install`

but it seems like I installed the one for python2.7.

How can I install the one for python3.2? Or convert the 2.x to 3.x?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply specify the version you wish to use, e.g. `python3 setup.py install`.

Comment: Installed correctly! Thanks!